# How to find if Url is Audio/Video

Tags: android, url, audio, android-webview, content-type

I have a simple question I want to identify that which url is audio/video and which are not.

Everthing was working fine but I have problem now with some url shown as text/html on their Content-Type

Like this Url Below is shown as text/html in Content Type:  http://dl.blugaa.com/hd.blugaa.com/f613178a0d993f8645ed530896937a22/cizuv/70%20Hazaar-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3

But this url is shown as Audio :
http://mp3light.net/assets/songs/393000-393999/393496-the-hills--1439131681.mp3

Can Somebody Explain me why and how to identify url the best way.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identify the content of the response you will get until you actually execute the HTTP request. You can have url ending with any extension, buy the response is still different. I would recommend you trying to parse the response from HTTP request, and if it doesn't work or headers in response are not matching the expected one, simply popup an error message.

Comment: I think I will check the Url. If the Url contains (.mp3,.mp4 and like these) and the response headers is giving (Code: 302 Moved Temporarily) and the I will get the location header as the required url that is a audio/video file.. 
Will this be a good Idea?

Comment: You should think about it as a simple IO. Since you don't know the content of the response, you should try to parse the response (that means to execute it anyways), and if it doesn't work, say that format not recognized or so.

Comment: Thannks Lliaz Akhemedov for this help.